# Different result in debug a.k.a F11 vs "Build Solution"

Tags: c#

I detected a strange behaviour in one of my classes. If I debug the program it works as expected - it returns Array with Random length filled with random string elements from the "string [] basicJobs" which pass as a parameter inside the class constructor. 
The strange behaviour comes if I just start the program by Pressing F5. In that case the CreateWork() returns an array with random lenght but filled with IDENTICAL strings.

```
class WorkCreator
{
    private string[] basicJobs;
    private string[] createdJobs;
    private Random randWorkCount = new Random();
    public WorkCreator(string[] basicJobs)
    {
        this.basicJobs = basicJobs;
    }


    public string[] CreateWork()
    {
        Random randomBasicJob = new Random();
        this.createdJobs = new string[randWorkCount.Next(3, 20)];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.createdJobs.Length; i++)
        {
           // createdJobs[i] = this.basicJobs[randomBasicJob.Next(basicJobs.Length)];

           createdJobs[i] = this.basicJobs[Convert.ToInt16(new Random().Next(this.basicJobs.Length))];

        }

       return createdJobs;
    }

}
```

I found an workaround (the commented line of the code inside the `CreateWork()` ) , but I am still wondering what is the cause of these behaviour ... :( . I am using `Visual Studio Community 2013` and `.Net 4.5`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `new Random().Next` in a loop is a bad idea, since random seeding sucks (time based, updates only every 16ms or so)

Comment: @CodesInChaos That version is his workaround for the commented line....or not...

Comment: The commented line looks correct. The other line creates a new Random object each time and it uses the same seed - hence the same sequence each time.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. So in that case it looks like that it was working in debug mode because it simply get enough time >> 16 ms. 
That does make sense :)

Off topic the Convert.ToInt call is not needed since it returns Int anyway :)


P.S. Yes the commented line is "working" fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [documentation for System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) (first paragraph) it reads:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers. You can also work around it by modifying the seed value returned by the system clock and then explicitly providing this new seed value to the Random(Int32) constructor. For more information, see the Random(Int32) constructor.

And this is probably the best explanation for what is happening in your code.

If you single step your program, more time passes and the seeds differ and thus the strings you obtain. If you simply run the program, the seeds are identical as the line is executed without much delay.